# Java convert decimal to 12 bits with bit wise operator &

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

I'm using Java, for this.

I have the code 97 which represents the 'a' character is ascii. I convert 97 to binary which gives me 1100001 (7 bits) I want to convert this to 12 bits, I can add leading 0's to the existing 7 bits until it reaches 12 bits, but this seems inefficient. I've been thinking of using the & bit wise operator to make zeros all but the lowest bits of 97 to reach 12 bits, is this possible and how can I do it?

```
byte buffer = (byte) (code & 0xff);
```

Above line of code will give me 01100001 no?

Comment: 97 already has 12 bits if you say so, what changes is how you use it. How do you use it?

Answer (score 0):

> which gives me 1100001 (7 bits)

Your value `buffer` is 8 bits. Because that's what a `byte` is: 8 bits.

If `code` has type `int` (detail added in comment below) it is already a 32-bit number with, in this case, 25 leading zero bits.  You need do nothing with it.  It's got all the bits you're asking for.

There is no Java integral type with 12 bits, nor is one directly achievable, since 12 is not a multiple of the byte size.  It's unclear why you want exactly 12 bits. What harm do you think an extra 20 zero bits will do?

---

The important fact is that in Java, integral types (`char`, `byte`, `int`, etc.) have a fixed number of bits, defined by the language specification.

With reference to your original `code & 0xff` - `code` has 32 bits. In general these bits could have any value.

In your particular case, you told us that `code` was 97, and therefore we know the top 25 bits of `code` were zero; this follows from the binary representation of 97.

Again in general, `& 0xff` would set all but the low 8 bits to zero.  In your case, that had no actual effect because they were already zero.  No bits are "added" - they are always there.

Comment: But what does & 0xff do then? It ads a 0 to the beginning of 1100001?

Comment: Added to my answer.

Comment: Code has type int

Comment: OK, then it's got 32 bits, and the high-order 25 bits are zero. Same sort of argument applies.  Answer updated again.